# How to hook update_post_meta and delete_post_meta?

Tags: hooks, post-meta

I'm still struggling to get my head around this whole hooking into things, so I'm really stuck on trying to do the following task:

If `update_post_meta` is fired then check to see if the `meta_key` is equal to something (I want to trigger some code if a particular meta_key is used). If the meta key I'm looking for then run some code that will need to know the `$post->ID` of the meta key being updated.

I need to hook into the `delete_post_meta` too that kind of does the reverse as above.

Can anyone provide me with some example code for hooking into `update_post_meta` and `delete_post_meta`?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The `update_post_meta` hooks are called from the more generic [`update_metadata()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.2/wp-includes/meta.php#L79) function, so you might not have found it directly. The three hooks are:

- [`update_post_metadata`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.2/wp-includes/meta.php#L117), a filter which allows you to "hijack" the metadata update and do something else. If you hook up a function that returns a boolean, execution stops there and the boolean is returned.
- [`update_post_meta`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.2/wp-includes/meta.php#L144), an action that gets called *before* the data is updated in the database.
- [`updated_post_meta`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.2/wp-includes/meta.php#L152), an action that gets called *after* the data is updated in the database.

If the meta key did not exist in the database yet, `update_metadata()` passes control to [`add_metadata()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.2/wp-includes/meta.php#L14), which has the similar hooks `add_post_metadata`, `add_post_meta`, and `added_post_meta`. This happens before `update[d]_post_meta` gets called. So if you want to do something when the meta key is added *or* updated, be sure to hook into both the `update*` and the `add*` hooks - but notice that while the `updated_*` and `added_*` actions pass similar parameters, `update_*` and `add_*` do not (`add_post_meta` does not pass a meta ID first).

[`delete_metadata()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.2/wp-includes/meta.php#L157) has similar hooks: `delete_post_metadata`, `delete_post_meta` and `deleted_post_meta`.

Sample code:

```
add_action( 'added_post_meta', 'wpse16835_after_post_meta', 10, 4 );
add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'wpse16835_after_post_meta', 10, 4 );
function wpse16835_after_post_meta( $meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value )
{
    if ( 'wpse16835_meta_key' == $meta_key ) {
        wpse16835_do_something( $post_id, $meta_value );
    }
}

add_action( 'deleted_post_meta', 'wpse16835_deleted_post_meta', 10, 4 );
function wpse16835_deleted_post_meta( $deleted_meta_ids, $post_id, $meta_key, $only_delete_these_meta_values )
{
    if ( 'wpse16835_meta_key' == $meta_key ) {
        wpse16835_undo_something( $post_id );
    }
}
```

Comment: super thx for this. I was aware about `update_post_meta` using `update_metadata` and in there, there was hooks to `added_post_meta` and `updated_post_meta` but thats as far as I could get. I didn't understand how to use. But now I think I've got it :)

Comment: More specifically, the hook is `updated_{$post_type}_meta`

Comment: Is it possible to hook into where post meta is updated via the REST API? I want to make it such that post revision is created when only post meta is updated via the rest API.

Answer (score 9):

Jan answer covers pretty much it above except for the case where a custom metadata is deleted from the Edit Post page. This happens asynchronously as soon as you click on the "Delete" button under the metadata, via a call to wp-admin/admin-ajax.php. Unfortunately, that calls bypass the `delete_metadata()` function in meta.php and calls `delete_meta()` in wp-admin/includes/post.php instead (not to be confused with wp-includes/post.php).

There are 2 actions that can still be used though, `delete_postmeta` (before deletion), and `deleted_postmeta` (after deletion). Both accept a single parameter `$mid`, which is the ID of the metadata (*not* the key). You can retrieve the metadata object using:

```
$meta = get_post_meta_by_id($mid);
```

which returns an object with meta_id, post_id, meta_key abd meta_value. Of course, by the time `deleted_postmeta` is called the metadata has been deleted so `get_post_meta_by_id()` won't work (which kinda makes that action useless)

Same goes for updating a custom metadata from the Edit Post page. The `update_metadata()` function (and its actions) in meta.php is *not* called, but the `update_meta()` function in wp-admin/includes/post.php is instead. Two actions again here, `update_postmeta` and `updated_postmeta`. The args are $meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value.