# is there an update_post_meta action

Tags: actions, post-meta

Are there any actions I can hook into for update_post_meta()?  I don't see anything obvious in the source.  Woocommerce lets you change the featured status of items via ajax from the edit screen.  I am using a transient to store the featured items in lieu of querying them every time and I'm deleting that transient on the save_post hook, but it isn't getting fired because of the ajax function that directly updates the post meta.  Worst case I can unhook woo's action and recreate it myself with the delete transient call, but I'm wondering if there is another hook i could use.

Comment: Maybe that already answers what you are looking for? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16835/how-to-hook-update-post-meta-and-delete-post-meta

Comment: ... I wish I'd searched first...

Comment: yeah me too.  face palm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

([See codex](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.2/wp-includes/post.php#L1469)) `update_post_meta()` calls

```
update_metadata('post', $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value);
```

This function [is here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.2/wp-includes/meta.php#L82). And there are plenty of hooks/filters:

(In example of 'post', `$meta_type='post'`)

### Before metadata is updated:

`update_{$meta_type}_metadata` ([here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.2/wp-includes/meta.php#L122))  **Filter**

-*If this returns anything other than 'null', the metadata won't save*

`update_{$meta_type}_meta` ([here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.2/wp-includes/meta.php#L149)) **Action**

### After metadata is updated:

`updated_{$meta_type}_meta` ([here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.2/wp-includes/meta.php#L158)) **Action**

`updated_post_meta` ([here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.2/wp-includes/meta.php#L161)) **Action**

-*For posts only*

All the actions take `($meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value)` as arguments. The filter filters a `$check` and takes the above as additional arguments.

Comment: appreciate you posting the answer even though it was a duplicate question.  sorry about that!