# Filter For Featured Image

Tags: post-thumbnails

Is there a filter for when a Featured Image is set/unset or changed.

I need to delete transient data when the above occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post featured image ID is stored as post metadata, so I would recommend hooking into the `update_post_meta` or `update_post_metadata` hooks, and then query the post meta for `'_thumbnail_id'` being set.

[See this related answer from Jan Fabry](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/16840/3966).

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'admin_post_thumbnail_html'. The simple function below will append 'This is a lovely image' to the image returned when you set the post featured image buut since $content is just an HTML string you can manipulate it in any way you want.

```
add_filter( 'admin_post_thumbnail_html', 'my_image_selected', 10, 2 );
function my_image_selected( $content, $post_id ) {
    return $content . 'This is a lovely image';
}
```