# Can't get post ID in functions.php?

Tags: functions, id

I need the current post id in a function , which I have written in functions.php. But I can't get the id. I have tried several method.

Like

```
get_the_ID(); //returns false 


global $post;
$id = $post->ID; //returns null  

global $wp_query
$id =$wp_query->get_queried_object_id(); //returns 0 

$url = 'http://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$id = url_to_postid($url); //returns 0
```

I am using the latest version of wordpress . What can I do now?

**UPDATE:**
I need post id in the function below.

```
function em_change_form(){
    $id = get_the_ID();
    if(isset($_GET['reg_typ'])) {
        $reg_type = $_GET['reg_typ'];
        if($reg_type =='vln'){
            update_post_meta($id,'custom_booking_form', 2);
        } elseif ($reg_type == 'rsvp') {
            update_post_meta($id,'custom_booking_form', 1);
        }
    }
}

add_action('init','em_change_form');
```

Comment: What is you function? [Edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/177262/edit) you question and post function code.

Comment: if the function is: `function example(){ global $post; return $id=$post->ID; }` and is used in `single.php`, or `page.php` in general it should return the id of that post/page, and to see that in action you have echo it in there `echo example();`

Comment: @Roberthue I have edited my question

Comment: @MayeenulIslam  actually I do not need to pring anything , I just need to update meta value upon a form submit or when a specific link is clicked .

Comment: @user1750063 I know that. I just meant, you can test it.

Comment: The init hook is fired before the post id is set, so it will always return false, null or 0

Comment: Then How can I have post id in that function ? @PieterGoosen

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/16835/31545)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The post ID is available after the query has been fired.

The first hook that is safe to get post id is [`'template_redirect'`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/).

If you can modify your function to accept a post id as argument, like so:

```
function em_change_form($id){
    $reg_type = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'reg_typ', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if($reg_type === 'vln'){
      update_post_meta($id,'custom_booking_form', 2);
    } elseif ($reg_type == 'rsvp') {
      update_post_meta($id,'custom_booking_form', 1);
    }
}
```

You can do:

```php
add_action('template_redirect', function() {
  if (is_single()){
     em_change_form(get_queried_object_id());
  }
});
```

I've used [`get_queried_object_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/) to obtain current queried post id.

If you absolutely need to call your function on an early hook like `'init'`, you can use [`url_to_postid()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/url_to_postid/), and [`home_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/home_url/) + [`add_query_arg()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/) to obtain current url:

```php
add_action('init', function() {
  $url = home_url(add_query_arg(array()));
  $id = url_to_postid($url);
  if ($id) {
     em_change_form($id);
  }
});
```

Note that second method is less performant because `url_to_postid()` forces WordPress to parse rewrite rules, so if you can, use the first method.