# Get post id outside loop : Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: posts, functions, loop

I am trying to get the post id outside the loop in functions.php.but what error i am getting : `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in functions.php on line 549`

```
function theme_myeffecto_disable() {
  global $wp_query;
  $post_id = $wp_query->post->ID;

  $showreaction = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_reaction_show', true );
  $showreaction = isset($showreaction) ? $showreaction : true;
  var_dump($showreaction);
}
add_action( 'init', 'theme_myeffecto_disable', 20 );
```

and `$showrating` always comes false weather it is true or false :(

Comment: Are you trying to get the id of the post when on a single post view only?

Comment: The query hasn't run yet on the `init` action, it's too early.

Answer (score 0):

You can not get post ID in `init` hook. The first safe hook to get post id is `template_redirect`.

See [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/177287/56815) answer for more details:

Answer (score 0):

you could simply just add this in your template

```
<?php
 global $post;

if($post >= 1) {
echo $post->ID;
}
?>
```

or if you want it in your functions.php and use it any where

```
function get_my_post_id() {

  global $post;

   if($post >= 1) {
    echo $post->ID;
}
}

add_shortcode( 'post_id', 'get_my_post_id' );

// then add the shortcode in your template file where you want the post_id output
<?php echo do_shortcode('[post_id]'); ?>
```

Comment: If there is no global post, your code will throw the same notice as stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

[Rizwan](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/56815/rizwan) Mention before you can't use [`init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/) hook for this. The first hook that is safe to get post id is [`template_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/). [Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177262/cant-get-post-id-in-functions-php/177287#177287) you can see details. I've used [get_queried_object_id()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/) to get current post id.

```
add_action('template_redirect', function () {
    $post_id = get_queried_object_id();
    // if post id available, this will not execute in archive pages.
    if ($post_id) {
        $showreaction = get_post_meta($post_id, 'post_reaction_show', true);
        $showreaction = isset($showreaction) ? $showreaction : true;
        var_dump($showreaction);
    }
});
```