# Is there a hook / action that is triggered when adding or removing a post thumbnail?

Tags: custom-field, post-thumbnails, post-meta, featured-post

I'm trying to update a custom field after a post thumbnail (Featured Image) is either added or removed from a post. The aim of this is to keep track of whether a featured image has been added or removed in order to do a synchronised export of only the updated 'dirty' posts for use in an external service.

I've looked throughout the codex for a hook that would be triggered after a post_thumbnail is set but I haven't been able to find anything. The solution I'd hoped would work was to use the slimly documented 'updated_post_meta' action (not to be confused with 'update_post_meta'!), using the following code:

```
add_action('updated_post_meta', 'check_dirty_fields_updated_post_meta', 10, 4);
function check_dirty_fields_updated_post_meta($meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value) {
    if ('_thumbnail_id' == $meta_key) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'thumbnails_dirty', 1);
    }

    if ('schedule' == $meta_key) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'schedule_dirty', 1);
    }
}
```

So, 'updated_post_meta' should be triggered whenever post_meta is updated, but unfortunately '_thumbnail_id' never gets triggered so the 'thumbnails_dirty' custom field that I subsequently want to set doesn't get updated.

You'll see from that code that I'm also checking to see if a meta_key of 'schedule' is ever updated and then marking another custom field called 'schedule_dirty' (the 'schedule' post_meta value is a custom field that gets set within the standard post UI) In the case of this more standard custom field the 'updated_post_meta' action does see it when it's updated and set the 'schedule_dirty' as intended.

The problem I have is that I can't see why the '_thumbnail_id' post_meta isn't triggering the 'updated_post_meta' action.

Compounding the problem further I just can't find any clear documentation on when the post thumbnail is set and subsequently updating it's related '_thumbnail_id' post_meta field. I note that when setting the Featured Image on a post that this is set straight away and therefore does not seem to be dependent on the 'save_post' action, so whilst I have looked through various aspects related to saving posts I think the answer lies elsewhere.

A few other bits of info that might be relevant to know:

- The posts in question here are a custom post type
- I'm also using the [Multiple Post Thumbnails plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-post-thumbnails/) and
  subsequently want to check for the updated state of these additional
  post thumbnails too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to use the `added_post_meta` hook instead of `updated_post_meta` because you're not updating the meta here, only adding it. At least in the case of the `_thumbnail_id`, where we must delete it before adding it again (no update) through the admin UI.

Investigating this further we see that this part of the `update_metadata()` function:

```
if ( empty( $meta_ids ) ) {
    return add_metadata($meta_type, $object_id, $meta_key, $passed_value);
}
```

is causing you the problem, because it calls `add_metadata()` and returns it,  before the `update_{$meta_type}_meta` and `updated_{$meta_type}_meta` hooks are ever fired.

You therefore need to hook into the `add_metadata()` function, instead of the `update_metadata()` function, through e.g. the `add_{$meta_type}_meta` (*before*) or `added_{$meta_type}_meta` (*after*) hooks.

If we check out the `wp_ajax_set_post_thumbnail()` function, that's ajax-requested from the admin UI when adding/removing the featured image, we see that it uses the functions 
`set_post_thumbnail()` and `delete_post_thumbnail()`.

The latter one is a wrapper for `delete_metadata()`, that fires up the `delete_{$meta_type}_meta` (*before*) and `deleted_{$meta_type}_meta` (*after*) hooks.

Comment: Thanks Birgire, this makes sense in retrospect that _thumbnail_id is removed as soon as we click the "Remove featured image" link below the Featured Image. I was forgetting that it actually removed it straight away via an AJAX call. I have to wait a few hours before I can award the bounty but I'll do so later on.

Comment: You're welcome @RickCurran, you had it 99% figured out,  glad I could help with the remaning 1% ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a working example that hooks into the add / remove events for a post thumbnail. It also includes the meta key required for the Secondary thumbnail created by the MultiPostThumbnail. Help for this solution came from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16835/how-to-hook-update-post-meta-and-delete-post-meta) and the MultiPostThumbnail docs. birgire gives a good explanation about these hooks in the accepted answer.

```
// Initialize the MultiPostThumbnails based on https://github.com/voceconnect/multi-post-thumbnails/wiki

if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) {
    new MultiPostThumbnails(
        array(
            'label' => 'Secondary Image',
            'id' => 'secondary-image',
            'post_type' => 'post'
        )
    );
}

// Listen for Updates

add_action( 'added_post_meta', '___after_post_meta', 10, 4 );
add_action( 'updated_post_meta', '___after_post_meta', 10, 4 );

function ___after_post_meta( $meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value )
{
  if( $meta_key === '_thumbnail_id' ){

    // Primary Thumbnail Added
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'thumbnails_dirty', 1);

  } else if ( $meta_key === 'post_secondary-image_thumbnail_id' ) {

    // Secondary Thumbnail Added
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'thumbnails_dirty', 1);
  } 
}

add_action( 'deleted_post_meta', '___deleted_post_meta', 10, 4 );

function ___deleted_post_meta ( $deleted_meta_ids, $post_id, $meta_key, $only_delete_these_meta_values )
{
  if( $meta_key === '_thumbnail_id'){

    // Primary Thumbnail Deleted
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'thumbnails_dirty', 1);

  } else if ( $meta_key === 'post_secondary-image_thumbnail_id' ) {

    // Secondary Thumbnail Deleted
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'thumbnails_dirty', 1);
  } 
}
```