# How to track product price changes?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

I am writing an API plugin. Every time a product or quantity changes in woocommerce, I need to export a new price to the server.
Also in the IPA there is import, which I will conduct through cron.

Help me find a way.
Thank.

Comment: Can I get product changes?

Comment: Probably. How are price and quantity stored in WooCommerce - as post_meta? [How to hook post meta updates](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16835/how-to-hook-update-post-meta-and-delete-post-meta).

Comment: Yes, as post_meta. 
Do you offer to listen to all post_meta changes and catch the necessary keys?
@Rup

Comment: Like this?
function update_price_hook ($meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value) {
            if ($meta_key == '_price' || $meta_key =='_regular_price') {
                //To do
            }
        }